# UI Approach to Question/Reply Table

Tags: usability, web-app, design-patterns, design

I got Project of One table which needs to be designed as per latest Design Standards, Old Table has a data of Question, Question's date & time, Reply and Reply Date & Time, UX perspective this table is not feasible when very Long Question or Ans. (Reply) comes as Input data. So i came around on this UI Design, I tried to follow Google Search format for that. is it most out of it or i could add something else, input i got client is that their users cannot make difference in date question posted and date of reply.

**Old Data - Tabular Layout**
[image: Old Layout]

**New Approached Prototype** 
[image]

There will be multiple blocks of question/reply based on data just like table,
What Could be the Best Possible method to convey approach?

Comment: What do your users need? How will they find the question that relates to their needs and how much 'preview' information do they need to see if the question answers their query?

Comment: ex: in diff form : admin will ask pre defined question, user will add their reply, ans. and on submit this table is showing.. which will be going to display on admin side, but it's very cluttered with big answers.

Answer (score 1):

From what get from your brief is that, you are required to redesign the tabular data in a more modern interface. I saw your redesigned prototype, and feel that it isn't in a tabular form as the brief indicated.

From the old table design, I noticed that the priority is in the Question, time and replier and reply time. The answer field has less priority. If that is the case, my approach would be to keep the data in a tabular form so that it is easier to search and sort. What you can do is, keep the data in a tabular form and when the cursor hovers over a question, expand it in a drop-down form to show the answer. This is way you can show more data by occupying less screen real-estate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know **Quora**?
[image]

Also stackexchange is site with question.

Important elements in the implementation are the elements that you design in order for the API to create the model (date, description, title, etc.)

**Which form will be the most pleasant and useful for users?**

Many aspect question, but changing the old layout to a new one seems sensible.
Also wondering which information is needed for the user or asking him here is a good solution. I think a necessary issue is search.

Comment: As Mentioned in comment of my post , used inputed data will be parsed in admin side, search option is not required because table will be shown based on user selection so. main approach is the layout with good readability.

Comment: Quara is also Good Example but User information is not required  (click to user profile etc.). just which user replied is is necessary so.